# I logged into my system but Unity doesn't seem to come up. Maybe it has crashed

Tags: unity, system, crash

I have a problem, because it looks like Unity has crashed.
Today I logged into my system, but the panel and the launcher don't came up.
I only see my files that I stored on the desktop.
Please help me, because I don't want to lose my data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the symptom of unity (or Compiz) crashing.  Your data is still safe.

Your best bet is to report a bug.  To do that, open a terminal (control-alt-T should still work) and enter the following command.

```
ubuntu-bug unity
```

Follow the prompts.